# How to make sure a a particular piece of jQuery is the very last thing loaded

Tags: jquery, joomla

Heres the code I'm using:

```
murl = window.location.href;
murl_arr = murl.split("#");
if(typeof murl_arr[1] == "string") {    
    jQuery('.rtg-categories li:nth-child('+murl_arr[1]+') a').trigger('click');
}
```

This website uses Joomla.

What I'm trying to do is after the page loads, get the URL, get the number from the URL and then select the list item with that number. I know this code works because I've used it in google chromes console.

The problem is this doesn't work automatically and I believe its because this loads before the list is created. I have no control over when the list is created because it is a third party component for joomla. So how do I make absolutely sure that the above code is the very last thing to load on my joomla webpage?

P.S. I've tried to wrap the above code in `jQuery(window).load(function() {` and sticking in just before the closing body tag but it still does not seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: use $(window).load() and add the code inside this function

Comment: Hi @Lucky, thanks for responding. When I use `$(window)` instead of `jQuery(window)` I get $ is not a function. this is what I tried to wrap the code in `$(window).load(function() { /*code here */ });`

Comment: jQuery(window) should work too,

Comment: Still doesn't work. I feel like I'm doing something really stupid that I'm overlooking here. Here's the link to the website if you want to have a look http://ultraspec.co.nz/gallery.html the gallery should change tabs if the url has #4 or something in it.

Comment: I am using chrome and the url doesnt get to the #var part

Comment: Also change the line to this - jQuery(".rtg-categories li:nth-child('+murl_arr[1]+') a").trigger('click'); - possible even the + sign should be repositioned for murl_arr

Comment: Sorry, http://ultraspec.co.nz/gallery.html#3

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: Sorry, use this url http://ultraspec.co.nz/gallery.html#3
So I copy and pasted the line you gave me, now the gallery has stopped working and the console is showing `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child`

Comment: Thanks for responding @fauxserious if I use that in the console it works, but not if I'm trying to load it in the page.

Comment: Are you positive that element will always eventually be on the page?

Comment: Yes, the list is always loaded on the gallery page. But I think the component I'm using creates the list after the above jQuery runs somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!
The problem was the list was created *after* the images loaded, so my code was executing after all jQuery was loaded, but before the list was created.

I fixed this problem by using [this jQuery plugin](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) which waits for images to be loaded before running the code inside it.